# How to use ngChange on a div (or something similar)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had an input that had `ng-change` on it, then I changed it to a `contenteditable` div, so I can have a little more control over what I can do with the input. But the thing is that when I changed from an input to a div, I am no longer able to use `ng-change`. What can I do obtain the same effect/result?

Here is how I am using it in my template:

```
<div class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="searchChanged()" contenteditable="true">{{seach}}</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inorder to support `ng-model` with `ng-change` for anything other than form element, you would need to create a custom directive. For example a simple implementation as below directive named `contenteditable` (much similar to angular having internal directives for `input`, `form` etc), have it require `ng-model` and on `keyup` event set the viewvalue and render the ng-model. When you `setViewValue` for the `ng-model` and values are different than prev value angular will evaluate the `ng-change` expression.

```
.directive('contenteditable', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

          function updateViewValue() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(this.innerHTML);
          }
          //Binding it to keyup, lly bind it to any other events of interest 
          //like change etc..
          elm.on('keyup', updateViewValue);

          scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            elm.off('keyup', updateViewValue);
          });

          ngModel.$render = function(){
             elm.html(ngModel.$viewValue);
          }

        }
    }
});
```

and do:

```
<div class="form-control" type="search" 
      ng-model="seach" ng-change="searchChanged()" 
      contenteditable="true"></div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.seach = "Initial";
  $scope.searchChanged = function() {
    console.log('changed', $scope.seach);
  }
}).directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

      function updateViewValue() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(this.innerHTML);
      }

      //Or bind it to any other events
      elm.on('keyup', updateViewValue);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        elm.off('keyup', updateViewValue);
      });

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        elm.html(ngModel.$viewValue);
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Edit
  <div class="form-control" type="search" ng-model="seach" ng-change="searchChanged()" contenteditable="true"></div>
  {{seach}}
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I am getting this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=contenteditable

Comment: @TheBoogieMan You are missing `ng-model`. Inorder to use ng-change you must have an ng-model associated to the element. See my demo.

Comment: But I am using one `ng-model="search"`

Comment: @TheBoogieMan Did you check the demo? try doing exactly that. Also what version of angular?

Comment: It should work. Clear your cache (probably it is cached), inspect the element to see if rendered one has ng-model in it. Do you see it working in my demo?

Comment: Ahh I got it, I forgot I had 2 `contenteditable` items, and I didn't add the model to the second one, but all in all the code works! Thanks!

Comment: @PSL On chrome works as expected, but on IE11 the ng-change is always triggered even though I'm only using arrow keys. Have you experienced this before? cheers!

Answer (score 1):

ng-change only works on an input not a div. Try ng-click.

For an example of implementing a custom directive to bind a model to a contenteditable div, see [here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add ng-change to div element because it is not data source. But you can write custom directive to handle custom ng-change implementaion.

Answer (score 0):

```
// usage
<div ng-model="val" onChange="fireEvent(val)"></div>

// implementation
angular.module('app',[]).directive('contenteditable', [function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        function read() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
        }

        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function(){
               read();
               attrs.onChange(ngModel.$viewValue)
            });
        });
      }
  };
}]);
```

Try this one. It is my own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your directive link function looks like this:

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
```

then you can attach a viewChangeListener to ngModel.

```
ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
  $scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-change only works if an input is changed from not from js. So ng-change is only applicable to input tags.
Applying custom directive to a div might solve your problem.